# Control awesome window manager from console

Tags: shell-script, window-manager, awesome-wm

I would like to accomplish the follwing:

1. determine current tag X in awesome window manager
2. sleep for 10 seconds
3. Jump to tag X no matter what the current tag is.

I know i can control awesome via awesome-client via the command line.
However, i can not find a single working example for its usage.

Can anybody help out ?

Answer (score 6):

Getting the current tag:

```
echo 'local awful = require("awful") ; return awful.tag.selected(2).name' | awesome-client
```

Switching to tag 1:

```
echo 'local awful = require("awful") ; return awful.tag.viewonly(tags[2][1])' | awesome-client
```

In both cases it handles screen number 2